# How can I use R to perform an ordered factorization by length?

Tags: r

For example I have this vector:

```
df <- c(NA, "Travellers' Choice, Certificate of Excellence 2020, Certificate of Excellence 2017", "Certificate of Excellence 2017","Certificate of Excellence 2018, Certificate of Excellence 2017, Certificate of Excellence 2016")
```

I want to do something like this:

```
df.ordered <- as.numeric(factor(df, levels=length(df), ordered=TRUE))
```

To get this as output:

```
[1] NA 10 4 12
Levels: 4 < 10 < 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the levels the unique values in the vector:

```
as.numeric(factor(df, levels=sort(unique(df)), ordered=TRUE))
```

```
[1] 3 2 3 1
```

Comment: Maybe my example is a bit bad. Your example also just numerates the strings and dont sort them. Try for example this: df <- c("Word Word Word","Word Word","Word Word Word","Word"). And the output would be [1] 1,2,1,3 (edited my example)

Comment: OK, then we can ``sort()`` the levels? See edit

Comment: This still wont work with all examples. I edited my example again with other values. See edit. Output would be: [1] NA 3 1 2